# get_footer not showing for Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason my footer disappeared for my site http://juliannaspizza.com.

I checked the template file for the home page and `get_footer` is being called as shown below. Any idea why my footer is still not showing up?

```
  <?php
  /**
  * Template Name: Full Width Page
  *
  * @package Fortune
  */

 get_header();

 get_template_part( 'parts/single', 'page-header' ); ?>

<div class="container full-width-page">
<div class="row">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-12">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

        endwhile; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
     </div><!-- .row -->
 </div><!-- .container -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

This is what my footer used to look like (https://certifagift.blog/):

[image: footer]

Comment: Your footer is visible, Clear cache, or hard refresh...

Comment: i tried that. still not seeing my footer.

Comment: open private window in browser and check it..

Comment: i did that as well. still not showing up for me. did you see my edit and are you able to see the old footer i used to have?

Comment: If you change themes, does the other theme's footer show? Any errors on the server? Permissions on the files correct?

Comment: Sorry!! It is purchase theme? i'm correct if yes please check theme seiings.

Comment: Footer looks fine for me, just like in the picture.

Comment: The footer is there, but you are just missing the content that goes inside it. Likely missing widget information like the answer says

Comment: I'm seeing your footer, so I'd imagine that one of the widgets, or something else that hooks into wp_footer, is causing an error just for the logged in user (ie, you). Edit your **wp-config.php** file to change the line that says `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and see what error messages are printed when you reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widgets are gone. From the markup, it looks like your footer (which does appear) is expecting to have widgets, but *those* are not appearing. Go to *Appearance* -> *Widgets* in your dashboard and add your widgets back in, and you should be good.

Comment: this was the correct answer. i had my jetpack plugin disabled for testing purposes and totally forgot about it. thanks for helping out a newb!

Comment: Glad to help! :)